# Win 11 Regedit - set Default app for HTTP / HTTPS launch from app (e.g. npm run serve)

Tags: windows, windows-registry, file-association

I want a specific web browser to open when a Windows app calls to open a web browser. I've seen various solutions specific to Chrome, for example, but I'm not interested in Chrome-specific solutions.

Many solutions recommend editing the Registry

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command`
and
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\https\shell\open\command`

to reflect the .exe of the desired app. I see that my current registry entry there has

`(Default) REG_SZ "C:\path"`

where `path` points to an exe which is not used (e.g. `C:\portable\waterfox\waterfox.exe`).

That is, MS Edge is used. That entry is there becacuse I did once select Waterfox as the default app, but no longeer, and that was weeks and other desired default apps prior.

also under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command` is a second Name

`DelegateExecute` with a `REG_SZ` value of `{17FE9752-0B5A-4665-84CD-569794602F5C}`.

Using the Find command, i see that `{17FE9752-0B5A-4665-84CD-569794602F5C}` is present in many other default shell open commands, such as

`IE.AssocFile.{extension}` which has the **`DelegateExecute`** `REG_SZ` value as `{17FE9752-0B5A-4665-84CD-569794602F5C}`,

where the `(Default)` is `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %1` , and there are several with `(Default)` REG_SZ value of `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %1`

In my case, MS Edge is launching regardless of these entries. I presume it's because Edge now handles commands that would otherwise have launched Internet Explorer.

I've not seen other discussions address the `DelegateExecute` value in proposed solutions.

Would it be safe to change these executable paths to my preferred .exe location?
What is that value `{17FE9752-0B5A-4665-84CD-569794602F5C}` referencing in this instance?

What do you suggest I change to make Win 11 apps open the exe I want for "web browser" file types?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee the browser's location you need it to be installed at - which I believe would actually be your biggest problem - you could always make your own custom protocol under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` which will activate your chosen browser and it alone, regardless of local settings or Microsoft's interference in the OS

You can use the absolute path and a regular `REG_SZ` string value or add an alias `%BROWSER_PATH_ALIAS%` as an environment variable and expand it later by using a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` (Default) string value

This same path can have a `%1` suffix in case you want the URL arguments to be passed down to the browser as command line arguments

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\protocol_name
    (Default) = "URL:protocol_name Protocol" / Description of your choice
    REG_SZ - URL Protocol = ""
    
    shell\open\command
        (Default) = "absolute/aliased path to Browser_Executable"
```

Then you can either add an URL Association at User level in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, or at Machine level in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

Both have the same `SOFTWARE` and `SOFTWARE\Classes` keys necessary

The browser icon can reference a icon file in the browser's folder or the browser's own executable from which the icon can be derived by Windows

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE
    Browser_Company
        Browser_Name
            Capabilities
                URLAssociations
                    REG_SZ - protocol_name = "Browser_Name"

    Classes
        Browser_Name
            (Default) = "URL:protocol_name Protocol" / Description of your choice
            REG_SZ - URL Protocol = ""
            
            Application | In case you decide to add extra Browser_Company details
                REG_SZ - ApplicationCompany = "Browser_Company"
                REG_SZ - ApplicationDescription = "Browser_Extended_Name"
                REG_SZ - ApplicationName = "Browser_Name"
                ApplicationIcon = "absolute/aliased path to Browser_Icon"

            DefaultIcon
                (Default) = "absolute/aliased path to Browser_Icon"

            Shell\Open\Command
                (Default) = "absolute/aliased path to Browser_Executable"

        RegisteredApplications
            REG_SZ - Browser_Name = "SOFTWARE\Browser_Company\Browser_Name\Capabitilies"
```

This last key under `RegisteredApplications` is the main pointer you want for this protocol association to be displayed in the Settings app -> Applications -> Default Applications -> Default Applications by protocol section

The main portion regarding the keys in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` already existed in my current project, the remaining configuration I learned from this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27267886/1361831)

Comment: Thank you VERY much for the thoughtful reply. I will definitely look into this when I have time!

Cheers and best regards!

Comment: @SylvesterDeMouser yeah, no problem. I myself was looking into this and was familiar with half of what it took to call specific applications by custom URL protocol, I didn't know which exact key was required to make the association show in the specific Settings app section and learned it from that answer

Comment: @SylvesterDeMouser if you have tested this answer and it solved your problem, please mark it as the solution for your question. Thanks